# Grip for Shimano Nexus hub gear shifter

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, grips, nexus

Would you recommend for a good grip from Shimano Nexus shifter? I hardly find a good option. Ergon grips seem to be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a grip is a matter of personal preference. If you're worried about the fact that the Nexus shifters require a smaller grip on one side than the other (due to the shifter taking up room), you can get grips that are made to mate with an internal hub shifter like the Nexus.

Alternately, since these can be difficult to locate, you can cut down the grip on one side with a hacksaw blade. That's what I did on one of my folding bikes, and it worked fine.

Just be sure to cut the grip in a straight line. You can mark the location of the cut with masking tape or painters tape before sawing to get an even edge. The edge will be slightly rougher, but since it'll be sitting up against the shifter it won't be very visible. If you want to cut down a non-locking grip, you can probably do something similar.